# My regex that should only accept latin-based characters is acting strangely

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got a regex written to the best of my ability that allows the latin character set only with the option of a '-' that, if included MUST be followed by at least one other latin character.

My RegEx:

```
[\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FFA-Za-z]+(?:[-]?[\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FFA-Za-z]+)
```

I came to this after reading a few posts and rereading the manual to figure out the best way to approach this. This check is attached to a text field where a user types only their first name and then submits.

It works okay but there is certainly room for improvement.

Examples:

```
Tom         // passes  
Éve         // passes  
John-Paul   // passes  
2pac        // passes and removes numbers (not really what I want)  
John316     // passes and removes numbers (not really what I want)
```

What I would REALLY want to happen is a fail on those last two checks.
How would I revise it to get the outcome I'd like?

Comment: what is the outcome you want?

Comment: From what I see, you need to anchor the regex, add `^` at the start and `$` at the end. And I assume it is JavaScript. See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fM3aZ9/1).

Comment: Yes it is javascript... you know what? I was testing at http://www.regexr.com/ and I had added those to it but it would fail every time. Should have just listened to the manual and not fiddled on a testing tool, derp

Comment: Because you need to add `global` and `multiline` flags to test the pattern properly there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to anchor the regex by adding `^` at the start and `$` at the end. That way you will not let any other symbols in the input string.

I also suggest enhancing the pattern by moving `?` from after hyphen to the end (that will make regex execution linear as the hyphen has no quantifier and is required, thus, limiting backtracking):

```
^[\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FFA-Za-z]+(?:-[\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FFA-Za-z]+)?$
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fM3aZ9/3).

JS snippet:

```js
console.log(/^[\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FFA-Za-z]+(?:-[\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FFA-Za-z]+)?$/.test('Éve')); //=> true
console.log(/^[\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FFA-Za-z]+(?:-[\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FFA-Za-z]+)?$/.test('John-Paul'));  // => true
console.log(/^[\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FFA-Za-z]+(?:-[\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FFA-Za-z]+)?$/.test('John316'));  // => false
```

Comment: I do not know the word, I meant to say "way".

Comment: I know. I just thought it was funny since "wat" is a common meme among js programmers: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat see also: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=20BySC_6HyY

Comment: Oh, that is an *amazing* video! :) :) :) Thank you for cheering me up this morning.